# Can't reach Node JS api behind Cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am creating a simple rest api with hapi and using Cloud9 IDE. I can access the API endpoint within the same browser as the IDE uses but can't reach the api with code. Instead of JSON output I get the Cloud9 sign in page source.

Any ideas to set this up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workspace is probably private. You can choose to make your server public by performing the following steps:

- Sign into c9.io and open the workspace in question
- Click on the 'Share' menu on the top left of the IDE
- When the Share dialog opens, check 'Public' next to the 'Application' row
- Close the sharing dialog and test accessing your server from the api again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mutahhir. I don't want to make my code public. I suppose this also makes the code public, right?

Comment: Nope, just your server :) to make code public, check the one next to 'Editor'

Comment: I need a place to get rid of my frustration :-) I struggled with the exact same problem and it took me five days to figure that out on my own. Now that I know what the problem was it was easy to find this answer on SO, so at least I can upvote an answer.